# OAI-PMH service Provider

Tags: xml, oai

I am planning to create a OAI-PMH service provider. can someone guide me on how to stat the service from the beginning. Any help will be much appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: [Read this excellent list of startpoints](https://www.google.nl/search?q=build+your+own+OAI-PMH+service+provider), it'll guide you through the whole process

Comment: thank you soo much for the help, can u give me ur email to contact you??